# Trim a string in c# after special character

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I want to trim a string after a special character..

Lets say the string is `str="arjunmenon.uking"`. I want to get the characters after the `.` and ignore the rest. I.e the resultant string must be `restr="uking"`.

Comment: Find the relevant index with `IndexOf`, and trim with `Remove` method.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "special character"? Why don't you say, I wanna trim a string after a dot.

Comment: btw, it's not trim that you want, it's split

Comment: If this is a file path, consider `using System.IO;` and then `string str = "arjunmenon.uking";
            string trimmed = Path.GetExtension(str);`, but be aware that this method preserves the leading period `.`.

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
string foo = str.EverythingAfter('.');
```

using:

```
public static string EverythingAfter(this string value, char c)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return value;
    int idx = value.IndexOf(c);
    return idx < 0 ? "" : value.Substring(idx + 1);
}
```

Comment: This one will return `arjunmenon` for sample input.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek oops! fixing

Comment: Another possibility is to use `value.Substring(idx + 1)` even when `idx` is `-1`. But that depends on how he wants that case interpreted.

Comment: do you think it can throw an indexOutOfRange exception if the value after '.' is empty ? for ex : "arjunmenon."

Comment: @losSebos currently it will return `""` for that scenario, because that is what `Substring` will return

Answer (score 1):

you can use like

```
string input = "arjunmenon.uking";
int index = input.LastIndexOf(".");
input = input.Substring(index+1, input.Split('.')[1].ToString().Length  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Regular Expression Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string input = "arjunmenon.uking";
        string pattern = @"[a-zA-Z0-9].*\.([a-zA-Z0-9].*)";

        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
       {
         Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
         if (match.Groups.Count > 1)
            for (int ctr = 1; ctr < match.Groups.Count; ctr++) 
               Console.WriteLine("   Group {0}: {1}", ctr, match.Groups[ctr].Value);
      }

    }
}

Result:
arjunmenon.uking
    Group 1: uking
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Split** function
Try this

```
string[] restr = str.Split('.');
//restr[0] contains arjunmenon
//restr[1] contains uking
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char special = '.';

var restr = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(special) + 1).Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not like the methods that uses indexes, this one will allow you not to use the empty string verifications, and the presence of your special caracter, and will not raise exceptions when having empty strings or string that doesn't contain the special caracter:

```
string str = "arjunmenon.uking";
string restr = str.Split('.').Last();
```

You may find all the info you need here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I won't do the split and go for the index[1] in the resulting array, if you already know that your correct stuff is in index[1] in the splitted string, then why don't you just declare a constant with the value you wanted to "extract"?

After you make a Split, just get the **last** item in the array.

```
string separator = ".";
string text = "my.string.is.evil";
string[] parts = text.Split(separator);

string restr = parts[parts.length - 1];
```

The variable *restr* will be = "evil"

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "arjunmenon.uking";
string[] splitStr = str.Split('.');
string restr = splitStr[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way will be this:

```
string restr, str = "arjunmenon.uking";
restr = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
```